# ListView; Sort & Highlight columns

Tags: c#, listview

I was wondering 2 things.

1. How can I make it so when I click on a row it selects both columns?
2. How can I make it so it auto sorts them when they click a column?

If C# doesn't allow this then is there any libs I could use or anything easier? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want more of a DataGridView...? WinForms?

Comment: You should describe what your GUI interface looks like, what it's trying to accomplish, and what framework you are using. Screenshots would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean your listview has 2 columns and you want to select the both of them on row selection, you can just set FullRowSelect=true.

For your second question check this [Sorting ListView Items by Column Using Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx)